# recurring segmentation fault while using strcpy

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, malloc

Getting a segmentation fault for the following code. Please advise.

```
struct columns {
      char* c_name;
      char* c_type;
      char* c_size;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int column_num = 3;
  struct columns col[10];
  //columns *col = (columns*) malloc (sizeof(columns) * column_num);
  strcpy(col[0].c_name, "PSID");
  strcpy(col[0].c_type, "INT");
  strcpy(col[0].c_size, "4");
}
```

I am using 2 ways to allocate space for columns structure but continue to get a segmentation fault. Am I missing something?

Comment: that's the most asked question on SO...

Comment: C or C++? This is important, the way you'd ("idiomatically") do this is different in both languages.

Comment: Your main needs a return statement.

Comment: If you're writing C++ use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (`strdup` takes care of storage but remember to free when you are done):

```
struct columns {
  char* c_name;
  char* c_type;
  char* c_size;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int column_num = 3;
  struct columns col[10];

  col[0].c_name = strdup("PSID");
  col[0].c_type = strdup("INT");
  col[0].c_size = strdup("4");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

None of your pointers in the structure are actually initialized to anything. You have to give them a dimension, or dynamically allocate some memory for them.

Answer (score 2):

`col[0].c_name` is a pointer, but doesn't point to any memory. That's why it will segfault.

Before copying anything in it allocate some memory using an array `char c_name[256];` or `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate memory and initialize your `char*` pointers.

Like

```
strcpy(col[0].c_name=malloc(sizeof "PSID"),"PSID");
```

Of course, you need to check for errors and make it otherwise meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate space for `columns` structure, but not for strings that you want to store. Your pointers (i.e. `c_name`) are left uninitialized, pointing to some random memory locations, thus you invoke undefined behavior right away.